# What does bitwise operation n&(n-1) do?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I was trying to understand some code, wherein I found the statement:

```
n=n&(n-1);
```

What does this do?

Comment: If the result of `x & (x - 1)` is 0 then `x` is a *power-of-two*. See #9 on [this page](http://www.exploringbinary.com/ten-ways-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-power-of-two-in-c/).

Comment: If anyone knows where from i can learn such bithacks , Please share.Thanks.

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: If bit manipulation is something you enjoy, there is an excellent book called Hacker's Delight (2e) by Henry Warren that you will find to be delightful.  https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321842685

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That equation zeroes out the least significant non-zero bit in `n`.

If we assume 8 bits, then here is the back of the envelop explanation. Let `n` be 70.

```
n       = 01000110
n-1     = 01000101
          --------
n&(n-1) = 01000100
```

As a consequence, if the result is 0, it means there was only one bit set in `n` originally, which means it was a power of 2 (or it was 0 to being with).

If applied iteratively in a loop until `n` becomes 0, the number of iterations counts the number of bits set in `n` originally. However, most processors will have a built-in operation to do this for you.

---

If bit-hacks interest you generally, searching this site for "bithacks" generates many hits.

Comment: This does assume `n` is an `unsigned` type.   It will also indicate zero is a power of 2.

Comment: @Peter: It seems to work for 2's complement and sign-magnitude. Thanks for pointing out 0.

Comment: This is what you call the "Hamming weight" problem :)